# Reliably Broken Sort

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting, permutations

Given a list of positive integers that contains at least 3 distinct entries, output a permutation of that list that isn't sorted in ascending or descending order.

#### Examples

```
1,2,3 -> 2,1,3 or 3,1,2 or 1,3,2 or 2,3,1
1,2,3,3 -> 2,1,3,3 or 3,1,2,3 or 1,3,2,3 etc..
```

Thanks @Arnauld and @NoOneIsHere for the title!

Comment: Will the input always be sorted?

Comment: Must the sort be "reliable" in that given a given set of entries, it always produces the same permutation as output?  Or must it only be "reliable" in that the output is not sorted?

Comment: It must just satisfy the specs.

Comment: Would a nested array be allowed as output? e.g., `[2,[1,3]]`.

Comment: No, it should be one single array/list.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 34 bytes

```js
a=>[a.sort((x,y)=>x-y).pop(),...a]
```

Sort the array in ascending order, pop the last element and use it as the first element of a new array. Then destructure the remaining elements of the original array into the new array (In JS, both `sort` and `pop` modify the original array).

---

### Test it

```js
o.innerText=(f=

a=>[a.sort((x,y)=>x-y).pop(),...a]

)(i.value=[1,2,3]);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value.split`,`)
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Comment: Why cant you just do `a.sort()`?

Comment: @geokavel: Because JS's `sort` method sorts lexicographically.

Comment: So because it's already unreliably broken? =D

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
o↻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/9R2@7//6MNdYx0jHWMY//7AwA)

or

```
o↺
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/9R267//6MNdYx0jHWMY//7AwA)

Sorts then rotates the list

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ṣṙ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd840/P//f7ShjoKRjoJxLAA)

Comment: `Ṣṙ-` also works (just felt like saying that; you probably knew :P)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yep that works too, same bytecount :p

Comment: In which encoding is `Ṣṙ1` only three bytes? In UTF-8, it's 7 bytes.

Comment: @heinrich5991 Jelly uses a [custom codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: I feel like everyone who uses Jelly must have a browser extension which adds a button to automatically post the "Jelly uses a custom codepage" comment.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
S╙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f8/@NHUmf//RxvqKBjpKBjHAgA)

Sort and rotate to the right.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 3 bytes

```
n é
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=biDp&input=WzIsMSwzXQ==)

Sorts (`n`) the array and rotates it (`é`) one element to the right.

Answer (score 5):

## APL, 9 bytes

```
{1⌽⍵[⍋⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNWGj3r2PurdGv2otxtIxdYqGCoYKRgrGHNhypgAxS0UTBXMwSosgXxTIMsSyDZSMAEA)

**How?**

`⍵[⍋⍵]` - sort the list

`1⌽` - rotate by 1

Comment: Also works in GNU and ngn!

Comment: @Zacharý guess I'll just remove the dyalog...

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda a:sorted(a)[1:]+[min(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqji/qCQ1RSNRM9rQKlY7OjczD8iO/V9QlJlXopGmEW2oY6RjrGOiYxqrqfkfAA)

-1 byte thanks to xnor

Comment: ...How did I not see this basic logic. >.>

Comment: @totallyhuman lol all 3 of my answers do the exact same thing. but ha :P Also I merged your PR for iOS -> MacOS :P

Comment: Yeah, I noticed and deleted my branch. :P

Comment: Putting the `min` at the end saves a byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>7</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
.P1S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/AMPj//2hDHQUjHQXjWAA)

*-1 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman*

Comment: You can save a byte by using permutations: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.P1S&input=%5B314%2C+112%2C+938%2C+792%2C+309%2C+308%5D&debug=0

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks, I'll update it when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 31 bytes

```
Prompt A
SortA(LA
max(LA→B
dim(LA)-1→dim(LA
augment({B},LA
```

Prompts for input in the format `{1,2,3,4}`.

TI-Basic is a [tokenized language](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens), all tokens used here are one-byte.

Explanation:

```
Prompt A         # 3 bytes, store user input in LA
SortA(LA         # 4 bytes, sort LA ascending
max(LA→B         # 6 bytes, save the last value in the sorted list to B
dim(LA)-1→dim(LA # 11 bytes, remove the last value from LA
augment({B},LA   # 7 bytes, prepend B to LA and implicitly print the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
{Á
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@nDj///RhjogaKRjomMcCwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
{À
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@nDD///RRjoKJjoKxjoKpjoKhjoKRmC2SSwA)

Comment: [Ninja'd (almost)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138849/68942) :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 21 bytes

```
O#`
s`(.*)¶(.*)
$2¶$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fXzmBqzhBQ09L89A2EMmlYnRom4rh///GXMZcRlyGAA) Sort and rotate as per usual. At least there's no unary conversion this time.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>68</s> 37 bytes

```java
l->{l.sort(null);l.add(l.remove(0));}
```

-31 bytes thanks to *@Nevay* (forgot Java 8 had a `List#sort(Comparator)` method..)

Modifies the input-`ArrayList`, instead of returning a new one.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nU7LasMwELz7K@Yol1jp42hS6L0NhRxLDxtZaeXKkpHWLib4213ZDjTHUlgtzKzmUVNPhW@1q6uvyTStD4w6cbJjY@VNCWC7xSsl2p/AnxrHgXWhfOc4U5ZixAsZd84A41iHEymN/QyB3psKSjyFQMOziQybl0iXMb00kYmNwh4OO0y2eDxbGVO@cJ1NP62kqhJWBt34XovbPC/HqVylbXe0SXpxWHKa1EIcOBj38fYOytcKV9nz2sHp719yrRYlxQXdbe43DylmUTqpxKy5wMMQWTfSdyzblMHWXV//av4v@zEbpx8)

```java
l->{                   // Method with ArrayList parameter and no return-type
  l.sort(null);        //  Sort the input-list (no need for a Comparator, thus null)
  l.add(l.remove(0));  //  Remove the first element, and add it last
}                      // End of method
```

Comment: You can use `l->{l.sort(null);java.util.Collections.rotate(l,1);}` to save 16 bytes.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `l->{l.sort(null);l.add(l.remove(0));}` to save 31 bytes (requires the usage of a not fixed sized list).

Comment: @Nevay nice one, but... the parentheses are a bit off in regards to the documentation: the reality is that the optional operations `add` and `remove` must be implemented; nothing is said about fixed-sized list... Kevin Cruijssen, given that there are much better alternatives in the previous comments, I'll wait for an edit before +1ing.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>36</s> 37 bytes

```
import Data.List
f(a:b)=b++[a];f.sort
```

<s>Use view patterns to match on the head of a sorted version of the input list, then append the first item of the list to the tail of the remaining list.</s>

View patterns aren't worth it. Sort the list, take the head off, append it to the end. In this case, it turns out that the naive solution typed out compactly is the best.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Great idea to use view patterns, I didn't know about them before. Unfortunately, they are not enabled in standard Haskell, so per site rules you need to include the bytes for the command line flag `-XViewPatterns`. Counting those the standard way `f(a:b)=b++[a];f.sort` is shorter.

Comment: I somehow wasn't thinking about the flag needed. I guess I use them so much that I forgot that I turn it on in my Cabal files and that it's not part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>43</s>  19 bytes

```perl6
{first {![<=]($_)&&![>=] $_},.permutations}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWl1@iW5xfVKJg@786LbOouEShWjHaxjZWQyVeU01NMdrONlZBJb5WR68gtSi3tCSxJDM/r7j2f3FipQJcq4ahjpGOseZ/AA)

```perl6
*.sort[1..*,0].flat
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWl1@iW5xfVKJg@19LD8SINtTT09IxiNVLy0ks@W/NVZxYqQBXpGGoY6RjrPkfAA)

Note that `[1..*,0]` would result in `((2,3),1)`, so `.flat` is there to turn it into `(2,3,1)`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

```
RotateLeft@Sort@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/KL8ksSTVJzWtxCE4v6jEQVntf0BRZl6JgkNadLWhjpGOcW3sfwA)

Comment: Shorter: `RotateLeft@*Sort`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 7 bytes

```
&nasprl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tL7G4oCjn/39DBWMIBAA)

Ugh, ruining the sort is so expensive!

Explanation:

```
&nasprl

&n      # take input as a list of numbers
  a     # sort
   sp   # save top of stack and pop
     r  # reverse stack
      l # load saved item
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

Takes input from stdin. Sorts the list and then moves the first element to the end, ensuring that it is no longer sorted. Saved three bytes due to Giuseppe.

```
c(sort(x<-scan())[-1],min(x))
```

Another implementation, same byte count:

```
c((x<-sort(scan()))[-1],x[1])
```

Comment: `c(sort(x<-scan())[-1],min(x))` is 29 bytes using essentially the same idea as yours.

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 19 bytes

```
a=>sorted(a)[1to,0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@@@QZvs/0dauOL@oJDVFI1Ez2rAkX8cg9n9BUWZeiUaaRrShjoKRjoKpjoKJjoJxrKbmfwA)

-2 bytes indirectly thanks to xnor

<s>Not yet working on TIO; waiting for a pull.</s>

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
S╜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f8/@NHUOf//RxvqKBjpKBjHAgA)

I think this is dissimilar enough from totallyhuman's post to post a new answer; I hope you don't mind :P **EDIT**: DAMMIT YOU NINJA'D ME

Comment: Ninja'd you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 31 bytes

```
def f(a):a[1:]=a[a.sort():0:-1]
```

Yet another Python solution.

Sadly, this one has the same length to [HyperNeutrino's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138846/44718).

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>76</s> 67 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;a=>a.OrderBy(n=>n).Skip(1).Concat(new[]{a.Min()})
```

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @Patrick Stephansen.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY9BSwMxEIXv@ysGTwmsgeqx7h4sVhSLYg8eSg9jdiqh2UlNUqUs@9vXZAtWwaOPMAyZN99LdDhvHbuBsaWwQ02wPIRIrXow/F50BSRpiyHA09gfb7JCxGg0fDjTwAINC/k9Opmy5nvWV4bjal3CzFlLOhrHQd0Skzda3d3wviWPr5ayra5hA9WAVY3q0Tfkrw@Cq5qlWm7NTkykmjnWGAXT52rdoVrk7F4O0@JXbHIFZ0m9eBMp/YZEiN7wm7p3aeGshHQ2GQLj26CDSQkXJVxCL6Wc/g/rhPuT90zYjLgfeX1xrP3wBQ)

Comment: Save a few bytes: `a=>a.OrderBy(n=>n).Skip(1).Concat(new[]{a.Min()})`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes

requires PHP 5.4 or later for short array syntax.

```php
sort($a=&$argv);print_r([array_pop($a)]+$a);
```

sort arguments, replace 0-th argument with removed last argument, print.
Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61de8dc832ad8353be98057afb38130261abb47a).

---

The 0-th argument is the script file name, `"-"` if you call PHP with `-r`. `"-"` is compared to the other arguments as a string, and since `ord("-")==45`, it is smaller than any number. The numbers themselves, although strings, are compared as numbers: `"12" > "2"`.

`php -nr '<code>' 3 4 2 5 1` and `sort($a=&$argv)` lead to `$a=["-","1","2","3","4","5"]` →
`[array_pop($a)]+$a` is `[0=>"5"]+[0=>"-",1=>"1",2=>"2",3=>"3",4=>"4"]`,
which results in `[0=>"5",1=>"1",2=>"2",3=>"3",4=>"4"]`.

Comment: Can you explain why [array_pop($a)]+$a doesn't overwrite the 0th index of $a? For example: $a=[1,2,3,4,5], array_pop($a) = 5, $a=[1,2,3,4]. If you do [5]+[1,2,3,4], shouldn't it end up being [5,2,3,4] because both arrays have a 0th index?

I'm confused because the PHP manual says "The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored."

Comment: @jstnthms The `+` operator does not append, it merges (without reordering the indexes; but that doesn´t matter here). The important point is that `$a` points to `$argv` and `$argv[0]` contains the script´s file name, the arguments start at index 1. I extended the description. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
.>SQ1
```

## Explanation

`SQ` - sort input list

`.>SQ1` - rotate input list cyclicaly by 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
O#`
O^#-2`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fXzmByz9OWdco4f9/Yy5jLiMuQwA)

```
O#`     Sort the list
O^#-2`  Reverse sort the list other than the last element
```

This leaves the list with the 2nd highest element first and the highest element last which is never correctly sorted

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 3 bytes

```
ȯ1«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//8R6w0Or/6c@apv4P9pIwVDBOBYA)

Same as other answers: sort `ȯ` and rotate left once `1«`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 18 bytes

Submitted on mobile. Please don't kill me for problems.

```
->a{a.sort.rotate}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda a:a[1:a.sort()]+a[:1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKjHa0CpRrzi/qERDM1Y7MdrKMPZ/QVFmXolGmka0sY6RjqGOSaym5n8A)

`a.sort()` sorts `a` in place and returns `None`. `None` can be used as a slicing index and is the same as omitting that index.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda a:a.sort()or[a.pop(),*a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKlGvOL@oREMzvyg6Ua8gv0BDU0crMfZ/QVFmXolGmka0oY6RjqmOsY5JrKbmfwA) or [Verify all test cases.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRKlGvOL@oREMzvyg6Ua8gv0BDU0crMfZ/QVFmXomGeppGtKGOkY5xrKaCra26jgKCr8mFpgRTEVjZfwA)

Inspired by Shaggy's [JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138858/66459).

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
§›
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6r2GoYKpgrGCkYKj5/9DyRw27/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 23 bytes

```
f(x)=sort(x)[[2:end;1]]
```

Slightly shorter than, but equivalent to `f(x)=circshift(sort(x),1)`.
I wish I could makeamethod based on `select` that was more, compact but I can not

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 52 bytes

```
(let((x(sort(read)'<)))(rotatef(nth 0 x)(nth 1 x))x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcY7DoAgEAXAq2zne52/0ssQxUhCgCxbcPvVONWcOfXmaJqKOXI0YKBXNWgMF6eDJLRasHij2COzDP5ZvnDQ6VhklU12vg)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 36 bytes

```
#(let[s %](cons(last s)(butlast s)))
```

Stole the solution to sort it and push the last element to the start of the list.

Answer (score 1):

## TeX - <del>207</del> 183 bytes

```
\def\a#1 #2 #3 #4 {\ifnum#2#1#3\def\e{#3 #4 #2 }\else\def\e{#2 #4 #3 }\fi\e}\def\b#1 #2 #3 {\a< #1 #2 \a> #3 {} }\def\c#1 #2 {\ifnum#1=#2\let\b\f\def\d#1 {#1 \c}\else\let\d\b\fi\d#1 #2 }\def\f#1 #2 {#2 #1 }
```

This is the best I can do with a language that doesn't really have data structures, or many builtins.

The approach is to take the first three numbers we find, and do a broken sort as follows: Sort the first two by greater, and then take the second two by lesser. This should always result in our list being unsorted. It's convenient to ignore anything  but the first 3 unique inputs.

We also have a check for two of the same number in a row. In that case, we scan ahead until we find a different number, and then switch the two, ensuring that our list is out of order.

I'm gonna work on golfing this down, but it's the best approach I can think of.

EDIT: Considerable work has been put in to this, to make it more golfy and also actually work. So here it is:

```
\let~\def~\a#1 #2 {\if^#2~\e{\box9 #1 }\else\ifnum#1\h#2~\e{\hbox{#1 }\a#2 }\else~\e{\hbox{#2 }\a#1 }\ifnum#1=#2~\h{=}\setbox9=\lastbox\fi\fi\fi~\g{>}\e}~\g{<}~\h{\g}\everypar{\a}\x^
```

I changed the the method from inserting things into the input to one where we recurse, replaced \expandafter with \everypar, and added that when it finds an equal number, it grabs the last number typeset and saves it until the second to last slot, ensuring that 1 2 2 (the case that secretly broke the previous answer) will be incorrectly sorted as 2 1 2.

This is just a function, to properly use it you need to: have input stored on the variable \x (or you could type in a list of numbers, with a ^ as a delimeter).

If you'd really like to try this, then do this

```
\read1to\x
```

before the lines of this function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṠỤ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMCVFMSVCQiVBNCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTElMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDMmZmxhZ3M9) Sort and rotate left.

```
ṠṾ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMCVFMSVCOSVCRSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTElMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDMmZmxhZ3M9) Sort and rotate right.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
->(x){x.sort.rotate}
```

I can't figure out how to use lambdas on TIO, but I'll add a link when I do

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 33 bytes

```
DEF B A
SORT A
PUSH A,SHIFT(A)END
```

Modifies the array in place. This uses the simple sort+rotate algorithm, though there may be a shorter solution involving RINGCOPY or something (the problem being that COPY and RINGCOPY don't work well when copying between overlapping parts of the same array)